# How to use Transactions in AdonisJS?

Tags: javascript, knex.js, adonis.js

I've been trying to implement a simple transaction in Adonis.

The scenario is I have a table that has a unique field named `name` and want to rollback the transaction of a multiple create query when one of the items `name` exists.

```
const Product = use('App/Models/Product')
const Database = use('Database')

const data = [
  {
    name: 'name1'
  },
  {
    name: 'name2'
  },
  {
    name: 'name3'
  },
  {
    name: 'name4'
  }
]

const trx = await Database.beginTransaction()

try {
  await Product.createMany(data, trx)
  await trx.commit()
  return response.json({
    success: true
  })
} catch (e) {
  await trx.rollback()
  return response.json({
    success: false
  })
}
```

In the code above, products name2, name3, name4 exists and name1 is not. So now we assume that when it starts creating name2, it will throw an error and rollback the transaction.

But it didn't. name1 is still inserted and not rolled back.

Also tried

```
try {
  await Database.transaction(async (trx) => {
    await trx.insert(data).into('products')
  });
} catch (e) {}
```

But got the same output.

I am using mysql 5.5 by the way.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: make sure to put a `console.error(e)` to see if there is an error

Answer (score -1):

If i correctly understood your question, you dont want to save duplicate rows in the database. for this purpose just change your **Product** migration file like this and add unique option to **name** colume.

```
'use strict'
/** @type {import('@adonisjs/lucid/src/Schema')} */
const Schema = use('Schema')


class ProductsSchema extends Schema {
  up() {
    this.create('products', (table) => {
      table.increments()
      table.string('name').unique()
      table.timestamps()
    })
  }

  down() {
    this.drop('products')
  }
}


module.exports = ProductsSchema
```

Comment: Sorry. I think you did not understand my post.